# Is there a service that will auto scan a 'Terms if Service' to assess privacy issues?

Tags: privacy

Terms of Service agreements are very tedious and extensive, I am wondering if there exists yet in the privacy tools that are evolving a tool that will scan a TOS for common issues to privacy.

Comment: [EULAlyzer](https://www.brightfort.com/eulalyzer.html), made by the creators of [SpywareBlaster](https://www.brightfort.com/spywareblaster.html), may be able to help. But ultimately, there's no guarantee that an automated tool will catch everything. If you're really worried about what a ToS/EULA has in it, the best way to be sure is to read through it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No, and there likely won't be until AI takes over the Earth. A legal document must be read and understood -- there isn't any kind of automated reader that can point out issues for you. It is already difficult for humans without a law degree to do so.

Comment: buherator pointed to "terms of service didn't read" which has some standard system of rating the TOSs not reading them for you, but a way to gage if you should invest your precious time in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The website https://tosdr.org/ provides a service like this.

Comment: This is a service that provides an excerpt of the ToS of different providers, but the analysis of the ToS is still done manually by humans.

Comment: That seems to be quite a good solution.  Gracias.